# R gEcon session aborted

Tags: r, rstudio, abort

When using the gEcon package, the session gets aborted as soon as I run the "make_model" function.

I used the gcn file that comes with the package as an example: "rbc.gcn"

I am using Rstudio with R-4.2.2. on windows 10
The gEcon package is the version gEcon 1.2.1
https://gecon.r-forge.r-project.org/download.html

Tried running the function expecting the creation of the model object and instead R crashes saying that the session is aborted.

Comment: I'd first run your script outside of Rstudio to see if it's an issue with the IDE or not.

Comment: Since it is an issue with the IDE, can you post an issue on the rstudio github page? This error sounds like a bug: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues